# convert string to entitytype entityframwork

Tags: c#, entity-framework, casting, type-conversion

I wanna change string to an entityType exchange of using swich case statement to find the Type

something like:

```
private void methodName(string entityTypeName)
{
    Type myEFType = Type.GetType(entityTypeName);
    //object d = Activator.CreateInstance(type); //this create instance from my entityType very Well
    var myEFTypeCollection = _db.Set<(here need cast) myEFType>();
}
```

I think have to utulize **Convert.ChangeType()** but how?

Answer (score 0):

You may use MakeGeneric() Method

```
System.Reflection.MethodInfo mi = typeof(API).GetMethod("DoSomething", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
mi.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Type.GetType(entityTypeName))).Invoke(new API(),new object[]{_db});



 class API
 {        

     private void DoSomething<T>(DbContext db)
     {
       IQueryable<T> items = db.Set<T>();
      // Do something you need .....

     }
 }
```